# AgWordCloudModule Issue while Build Angular Application?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular7

We used `'angular4-word-cloud'` for word cloud graph in **angular 7** application.

Issue: After importing it as `'AgWordCloudModule'`, there is an issue when running it on prod build. The Error showing as ' Function calls are not supported in decorators but `'AgWordCloudModule'` was called.'

Comment: Please suggest the resolving answer it will be great..

Comment: Actually when we run it on prod build getting the below error:  ERROR in Error during template compile of 'PmaModule'
  Function calls are not supported in decorators but 'AgWordCloudModule' was called.

Comment: @NgModule({
  declarations: [WordcloudComponent],
  imports: [ AgWordCloudModule.forRoot() ],

  exports: [],
  entryComponents: [WordcloudComponent]
}) - Like this We are using it and when we run it on prod build getting the above showed Error.